# Creating search option in windows form from powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a windows form that's set to read only, I noticed that CTRL+F doesn't work. Is there a way to build a search function or bar to look at specific texts/strings in my windows form? Here is what my code looks like:

```
                # Create Window
 add-type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
 $form=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
 $form.StartPosition='CenterScreen'
                # Textbox
 $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
 $textBox.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
 $textBox.ReadOnly =$true
 $textBox.Multiline = $true
 $textBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
 $textBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",12)
 $textBox.ForeColor = "White"
 $textBox.Text = $object
 $textBox.BackColor = "Black"
 $Form.Controls.Add($textBox)
                # Button
 $btn=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $btn.Text='Finish'
 $btn.DialogResult='Ok'
 $btn.Dock='bottom'
 $form.Controls.Add($btn)
 if($form.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok'){
     $tb.lines
 }
```

Is it possible to handle this as a KeyDown event? And if so, how would you record CTRL+F and utilize it to search for text in the window?

Comment: You could add another textbox that's set to `.Visible = $false`, and then handle the KeyDown event for `$textbox` - if Ctrl+F was pressed, show the second textbox and use that for search inputs

Comment: Hello @MathiasR.Jessen I have attempted to look up how to utilize this method on the web. I do see what you're talking about. Could you by chance guide me on how to code this? I edited my question for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Create Window
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.Control -and $_.KeyCode -eq "F") {
        $stringToFind = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Find what", "Find")
        $pos = $textBox.Text.IndexOf($stringToFind);
        if ($pos -ne -1) { 
            $textBox.SelectionStart = $pos;
            $textBox.SelectionLength = $stringToFind.Length;
        } 
    }
})
# Textbox
$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
$textBox.ReadOnly =$true
$textBox.Multiline = $true
$textBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$textBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",12)
$textBox.ForeColor = "White"
$textBox.Text = $object
$textBox.BackColor = "Black"
$Form.Controls.Add($textBox)
# Button
$btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn.Text = 'Finish'
$btn.DialogResult = 'Ok'
$btn.Dock = 'bottom'
$form.Controls.Add($btn)
if ($form.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok') {
    $tb.lines
}
```