# How to color a searched string in text box, Powershell Forms

Tags: powershell, colors

Trying to write a simple Powershell form for searching strings. Two text boxes, one is for output the second is for searching.

Goal: write a string to find > press `enter` > searched string will be colored in output text(if found)

Example:

OutputBox - `text for example`

SearchBox - `ex`

After search action - `t/red>/ex/<red/t for /red>/ex/<red/ample`

Used code from [link1](https://superuser.com/questions/1270122/how-to-colorize-specific-strings-in-powershell-textbox) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285502/creating-search-option-in-windows-form-from-powershell) so far, and has two problems:

1. `appendtext` is not good in my case, it messes up my output content, trying to find a solution with `replace` method
2. I don't know why, but `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` from link2 doesn't work for me. It doesn't selecting the text, although it finds the right position with right length

Search code(link2 text selection case):

```
$SearchInput = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$SearchInput.Dock = "Bottom"
$Form.Controls.Add($SearchInput) 

$SearchInput.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter")
{
    $pos = $outputBox.Text.IndexOf($($SearchInput.text))
    if ($pos -ne -1) { 
        $outputBox.SelectionStart = $pos
        $outputBox.SelectionLength = $($($SearchInput.text).Length)
    } 
}
})
```

OutputBox Code:

```
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,250) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(780,405) 
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ForeColor = "White"
$outputBox.BackColor = "Black"
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
$outputBox.ReadOnly=$True
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few modifications with selection color (`$outputBox.SelectionColor = 'red'`) and added logic to color multiple occurrence of word ex.

code modification:

```
$SearchInput.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter")
{
$counter = 0
$pos = $outputBox.Text.IndexOf($SearchInput.text,$counter)
 while($pos -ne -1) {
 $counter = $pos + $SearchInput.text.Length
$outputBox.SelectionStart = $pos
$outputBox.SelectionLength = $SearchInput.text.Length
$outputBox.SelectionColor = 'red'
$pos = $outputBox.Text.IndexOf($SearchInput.text,$counter)
}
}
```

Standalone working version of script:

```
add-type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
$form=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.StartPosition='CenterScreen'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1000,1000) 
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,250) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(780,405) 
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ForeColor = "White"
$outputBox.BackColor = "Black"
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
$outputBox.Text = "text for example"
$outputBox.ReadOnly=$True
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox) 
$SearchInput = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$SearchInput.Dock = "Bottom"
$Form.Controls.Add($SearchInput) 

$SearchInput.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter")
{
$counter = 0
$pos = $outputBox.Text.IndexOf($SearchInput.text,$counter)
 while($pos -ne -1) {

 $counter = $pos + $SearchInput.text.Length
$outputBox.SelectionStart = $pos
$outputBox.SelectionLength = $SearchInput.text.Length
$outputBox.SelectionColor = 'red'
$pos = $outputBox.Text.IndexOf($SearchInput.text,$counter)
}
}
})

$form.ShowDialog()
```

PS: repeated selection part can be optimized

Comment: Works, thanks. Has an endless loop when searchBox is empty, but it simple to fix. Can you please explain the last line? Why you are doing it again?
 `$pos = $outputBox.Text.IndexOf($SearchInput.text,$counter)`

Comment: @igor indexof function second parameter is for the index position from which the search will start , indexof only finds the first occurrence and the loop is updating starting position with counter.